# React sibling communication with ONLY access to parent

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create something similar to [React Bootstrap's dropdown component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/).  My starting skeleton is something like the following:

```
import React from 'react';

const DropDown = props => {
  return <div className="dropdown-container">{props.children}</div>;
};

const DropDownToggle = props => {
  return <div className="dropdown-toggle">{props.children}</div>;
};

const DropDownContent = props => {
  return <div className="dropdown-content">{props.children}</div>;
};

export { DropDown, DropDownToggle, DropDownContent };
```

These components would be used like this:

```
<DropDown>
  <DropDownToggle>
    {/* 
      The content inside here should be customizable so the user of
      these components can specify whatever they want for the toggle
     */}
    <button type="button">
      my button
    </button>
  </DropDownToggle>
  <DropDownContent>
     {/* 
      The content inside here should be customizable so the user of
      these components can specify whatever they want for the content of 
      the dropdown
     */}
    <ContentComponent/>
  </DropDownContent>
</DropDown>
```

Is there a way I can communicate between the two children components (DropDownContent and DropDownToggle)?  I have access to the parent component and it just receives and displays the children so far, but I would like to somehow communicate between the children so that the user can click on the toggle to open/close the content.  I don't want to use redux.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

I ended up going with the method that @Train suggested in his/her comment below.  I was originally hoping for the ability to nest components manually, but what was most important to me was having the state be self-contained in the parent component.  Being able to define the toggle button's HTML as well as the content's HTML was also a requirement. My final implementation allows for both of these things and looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false,
  };

  onDropDownToggleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  };

  render() {
    let contentClasses = 'dropdown-content';
    if (this.state.isOpen) {
      contentClasses += ' show';
    }

    return (
      <div className="dropdown-container">
        <div className="dropdown-toggle" onClick={this.onDropDownToggleClick}>
          {this.props.toggle}
        </div>
        <div className={contentClasses}>{this.props.content}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Dropdown.propTypes = {
  toggle: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.element]).isRequired,
  content: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.element])
    .isRequired,
};

export default Dropdown;
```

to use it:

```
const dropDownToggle = (
  <button type="button">
    Dropdown
  </button>
);
const dropDownContent = 'content';

<DropDown
  toggle={dropDownToggle}
  content={dropDownContent}
/>
```

Comment: Use Composition for something like this `https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html`

Comment: set a state for open/close in the parent, and send it in as a boolean prop to the content. Send a function prop to modify the state in the parent into the toggle component

Comment: @Train, if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it since it is what I ended up going with.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like toggling content you can use `composition` instead of `inheritance` to pass data around.

From the example of [Facebook](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

This is done with `props.children` property.

```
function Dialog(props) {
  return (
    <FancyBorder color="blue">
      <h1 className="Dialog-title">
        {props.title}
      </h1>
      <p className="Dialog-message">
        {props.message}
      </p>
      {props.children}
    </FancyBorder>
  );
}

class SignUpDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSignUp = this.handleSignUp.bind(this);
    this.state = {login: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dialog title="Mars Exploration Program"
              message="How should we refer to you?">
        <input value={this.state.login}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />

        <button onClick={this.handleSignUp}>
          Sign Me Up!
        </button>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({login: e.target.value});
  }

  handleSignUp() {
    alert(`Welcome aboard, ${this.state.login}!`);
  }
}
```

In the `render()` I am rendering the `Dialog` component and passing in the props.
the props are `.children` and the custom props `title, message`
This lets us pass child elements directly into the output we can even add components from other classes as I did with the `SignUpDialog`.

Comment: This is a good way to design things, but this wouldn't work for my original question because you have to have access to the childrens' code as well as the parent's in order to make them communicate.  I ended up using an example from the website link you sent, but it was a different example in order to do what I needed.  I used the third code block down under the "Containment" header when visiting that URL (starting with ..... function SplitPane(props) .... )

Answer (score 0):

Did you have something like this in mind?

```js
const actionTypes = {
  TOGGLE: "TOGGLE"
};

const notRedux = {
  actionHandlers: Object.keys(actionTypes).reduce(
    (acc, val) => ({ [val]: [], ...acc }),
    {}
  ),
  dispatchAction(actionType, data) {
    this.actionHandlers[actionType].forEach(handler => handler(data));
  },
  onAction(actionType, actionHandler) {
    this.actionHandlers[actionType].push(actionHandler);
  }
};

const DropDown = ({ children }) => {
  return <div className="dropdown-container">{children}</div>;
};

const DropDownToggle = () => {
  const onClick = () =>
    notRedux.dispatchAction(actionTypes.TOGGLE, "oh hi Mark");
  return (
    <div className="dropdown-toggle">
      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
        my button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const DropDownContent = props => {
  notRedux.onAction(actionTypes.TOGGLE, data =>
    alert(`DropDownToggle said ${data} //DropDownContent`)
  );
  return <div className="dropdown-content">{props.children}</div>;
};

const App = () => (
  <DropDown>
    <DropDownToggle></DropDownToggle>
    <DropDownContent>
      <span>Content goes here</span>
    </DropDownContent>
  </DropDown>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></app>
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but no. The structure is what I was looking for (nesting components), but the more important piece to me was to have everything self-contained within the DropDown component (which is why I said no redux).  I ended up following what @Train suggested in his/her comment.  I will edit the question to include what I ended up going with